# If field like 'something' clause in void function - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I need makes this function to load teams from pl_raw to new table named game.
In pl_raw to be all data. Now.. this function in order to order data for tables...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loadGames() RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN

IF (SELECT * from pldata.pl_raw where venue = 'Away') THEN
INSERT INTO definitiu.game (date_game, home_team, away_team)
SELECT game_date, opposition_id,team_id from pldata.pl_raw;

ELSIF (SELECT * from pldata.pl_raw where venue = 'Home') THEN
INSERT INTO definitiu.game (date_game, home_team, away_team)
SELECT game_date, team_id, opposition_id from pldata.pl_raw;
END IF;

END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

The function compile, but, Postgres return this error when I execute this function:

> ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
>   LINE 1: SELECT (SELECT * from pldata.pl_raw where venue = 'Away')
>                  ^
>   QUERY:  SELECT (SELECT * from pldata.pl_raw where venue = 'Away')
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function loadgames() line 4 at IF
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: subquery must return only one column
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Context: PL/pgSQL function loadgames() line 4 at IF

Comment: Well, the error message is clear: the result of the `select` statement must be stored somewhere. What exactly does the `select` return? You seem to be retrieving all columns. An `if` statement expects a boolean expression, not a list of rows with many columns. What exactly are you trying to do there?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to filter the data that goes into `pl_raw`? Or are you just trying to order the data in `pl_raw`? If you're just trying to order the data for some other query, you should use an `ORDER BY` on that other query. The table order doesn't even matter. PostgreSQL can return rows in any order it likes without an `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EXISTS:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * from pldata.pl_raw where venue = 'Away') THEN
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Work it at first try! :)